# regex misunderstanding in r

Tags: r, gsub, stringr, stringi

I don't seem to understand gsub or stringr.
Example:

```
 > a<- "a book"

> gsub(" ", ".", a)

[1] "a.book"
```

Okay. BUT:

```
> a<-"a.book"

> gsub(".", " ", a)

[1] "      "
```

I would of expected

> "a book"

I'm replacing the full stop with a space.

Also: `srintr`: `str_replace(a, ".", " ")` returns:

`" .book"`

and `str_replace_all(a, ".", " ")` returns

`"      "`

I can use `stringi`: `stri_replace(a, " ", fixed=".")`:

`"a book"`

I'm just wondering why gsub (and str_replace) don't act as I'd have expected. They work when replacing a space with another character, but not the other way around.

Comment: Escape the dot as this `gsub("\\.", " ", a)`. Otherwise, it will be treated as regex matching everything.

Comment: or `gsub('.', ' ', a, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: The first words in the documentation for `gsub`'s `pattern` argument are "character string containing a regular expression", where `regular expression` is actually a link to another topic. I suggest you read it.

Comment: okay thanks, that makes sense. Ive used them a bit as well as quotes like "\n" for new line. I just didn't know "." was a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the first argument to `gsub`, namely `pattern` is actually a regex. In regex the period `.` is a metacharacter and it matches any single character, see `?base::regex`. In your case you need to escape the period in the following way:

```
gsub("\\.", " ", a)
```

Comment: For information, you can also escape the meaning of `.` by enclosing it in a character class `[.]` it tends to be easier thans the `\\.` to read when you have multiples literal dots in your regex (I.e: in `\\w[.]\\d{2}[.][^.]+` is easier to spot the literal dots than in `\\w\\.\\d{2}\\.[^.]+`)

Comment: I'll use`[ ]` for everything now to avoid any future confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @OliPaul be carefull, `[abcd]` means any one of a, b, c or d (this is a character class) and not a followed by b, etc. the character class has its use. Regex are great but you have to understand them if you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot. As said in this answer and comments, read the doc :)